# API not updating table field - React Native App, AWS API and DynamoDB table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, api, react-native

Trying to update my DynamoDB table with my "Update" API. It is just not working. "Update" API will update the field "status" from "New" to "Read". No issue with the API as I checked it on Postman and it updates the field correctly.

```
export const updateNotifications = (id) => {

       if(id !== null){
        const config = getAppConfig();

        const cognitoToken = await getCognitoToken(config); 

        if (cognitoToken !== null) {
          try{
            let headers = {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': cognitoToken,
              'targetId': HAGo_getDeviceUUID(),
              'userId' : id
            };

            let body = { 'status' : 'Read' }

            let updateUrl = config["notification-update-api"] + '/' + id;

            await fetch(updateUrl,
              {
                method: 'PATCH',
                headers: headers,
                body: body
              })

          } catch (e) {
              // something went wrong
              console.log('error'); 
          }
        }
      }else{
        return null;
      }

    }
```

Am I doing this correctly??? Please help me fix my code!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it

Solution: json.stringify to the body fixed it.

```
export const updateNotifications = (id) => {

.
.
.
.
.

            let body = json.stringify({ 'status' : 'Read' })

            await fetch(updateUrl,
              {
                method: 'PATCH',
                headers: headers,
                body: body
              }

    }
```